# Ruling out dependence of y and z coordinates in Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, symmetry

Let us assume that motion is in the $x$ direction, axes of both coordinate systems are aligned and their origins meet at $t=t'=0$. The most general relation between $x$ and $x'$ then becomes (ruling out powers greater than 1 to not induce acceleration and because of homogeneity and isotropy of space arguments)
$$x'=Ax+By+Cz+Dt$$
Now if $B, C\neq 0$ then we get that if we place our object at different $z$ and $y$ at $t=0$ then we'll measure different displacements of our object in the primed frame, which is clearly in opposition to the homogeneity of the space.

Thus on this argument can one rule out any $y$ and $z$ dependence and directly say that $B=C=0$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say "if we place our object at different $z$ and $y$ at $t=0$ then we'll measure different displacements of our object in the primed frame". There is no way to set $B=C=0$ on the basis of any argument of homogeneity/isotropy of space/time or on the basis of Einstein's axioms of relativity. Proof: the most general set of transformations that are allowed under all those axioms is the Poincare group of transformations and it includes rotations.

Comment: @FreeAssange after reflection I too realized that my argument is flawed. Also as you said there is no way to say that B=C=0, on the basis of homogeneity/isotropy arguments, does one can explain this fact only by the usual principle of relativity argument or is there any other way too?

Comment: No, as I said, it's just not true that any principle of physics requires that $B=C=0$. You can obviously have transformations that have $x'=\cos\theta x +\sin\theta y$ and $y'=\cos\theta y - \sin\theta x$, for example. It's just a rotation.

Comment: @FreeAssange yeah again i was mixing some concepts, so in short B=C=0 is a postulate?

Comment: No! It is just not true that you should somehow have $B=C=0$! Let it be whatever it wants to be :) You can take it as an ansatz that $B=C=0$ -- which would mean you are interested in pure boost transformations.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem statement needs to more precisely define the specific transformation (i.e., among all metric-preserving transformations, what characterizes the form of the boost transformation that you seek?).